# Is Jquery broken? Why does Jquery Load fn not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery seems to have difficulty in IE (6,7,8) loading using the load() function when there are url's with parameters (example: getdata.php?id=2444)

I am having this problem, but it seems this question is common and has never been resolved:

see

[JQuery load() in IE8 POST&GET not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174945/jquery-load-in-ie8-postget-not-working) [jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)

Why hasn't this issue been fixed? Is there a solution using Jquery?

Comment: Assuming cpharmston is right (sure sounds good), this would be truly interesting, since the other questions you mentioned on SO don't load anything with a querystring :)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `$.load` function has a data parameter which takes JSON-serialized values and converts them to GET variables. Try this:

```
$.load('getdata.php', { 'id': 2444 });
```

Since `$.load()` is just a wrapper of $.ajax(), you can find more info at the [`$.ajax()` page](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) (go to the options tab, look for the `data` parameter). It was constructed this way to easily allow them to prevent caching (which is done by a GET variable of the timestamp) and do some nifty JSON serialization tricks (with the goal of making it easy to use JavaScript datatypes), such as:

```
var foos = ['bar1', 'bar2'];
$.load('getdata.php', { 'foo': foos });
```

The request for the above example: `getdata.php?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`

Comment: Wow? Leaky abstractions, these.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to explain it. It's certainly a leaky abstraction, but there are also some neat benefits.

Comment: Very interesting. Assuming this is intentional, can I also assume it's documented somewhere? Aside from here, I mean: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/18f03016212cf049